# Dependency injection does not work in spring boot test but works in normal development

Tags: dependency-injection, spring-boot-test

I started to develop a classical Spring Boot MVC application. I use dependency injection (using `@Service`, `@Autowired` annotation) without any problem.

When I try to run some integration test using dependency injection the same way I get the following error message from Junit:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'hu.bookandwalk.RepositoryTests':
>   Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userService'; nested
>   exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type 'hu.bookandwalk.services.UserService'
>   available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire
>   candidate. Dependency annotations:
>   {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

The relevant part of the test code:

```
package hu.bookandwalk;

...

import hu.bookandwalk.config.MyNeo4jConfig;
import hu.bookandwalk.domain.*;
import hu.bookandwalk.services.*;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@Transactional
@ContextConfiguration(classes={MyNeo4jConfig.class})
public class RepositoryTests {

    @Autowired
    Session session;

    @Autowired
    UserService userService;
...

}
```

In the `hu.bookandwalk.services` package I have a `UserService` interface without annotation and a `UserServiceImpl` class annotated with `@Service`.

I don't understand that if DI works for running my application than why it doesn't work in the test. Somehow my annotated implementation class is not discovered by spring boot as the error messages says.

The test is located in the same package as my application class: `hu.bookandwalk`
All my services, repositories, domains are located under this: `hu.bookandwalk.services`, `hu.bookandwalk.domain`, ...

Any idea what kind of annotation I miss for the test class to make `userServiceImpl` discoverable?

Answer (score 3):

Try to insert `UserServiceImpl.class` in `@ContextConfiguration`